# How to preserve the last appliaction state in android when returning back from the Web Browser in android

Tags: android

I am stuck with severe issue, I have an develop application in which iam redirect to the MAP browser showing the Route between Two cities , now when i press the back button on the Device my previous data are lost and i get unusual result.

How to solve the application preserving previous state

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState). For more info. click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state).